# Response error in API calling swiftui mvvm

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mvvm

I'm new with swift and I'm trying to make a small app that calls characters from [Rick and Morty API](https://rickandmortyapi.com/) and put them on a list.

The app compile but the character list doesn't appear. Instead, this error (handled by me) appear:

[image]

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3O90QGKv98&t=0s) tutorial and if I use the example API the app works fine but not when I use Rick and Morty API.

**CharactersModel**

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Tutorial Model
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let email: String
    let name: String
    let company: Company
}

struct Company: Codable {
    let name: String
}

// MARK: - Character
struct Character: Codable {
    let info: Info
    let results: [Result]
}

// MARK: - Info
struct Info: Codable {
    let count, pages: Int
    let next: String
    let prev: JSONNull?
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
import Foundation

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var characters: [Result] = []
    @Published var hasError = false
    @Published var error: CharacterError?
    @Published private(set) var isRefreshing = false
    
    func getAllCharacters() {
        
        hasError = false
        isRefreshing = true
        
        let baseURL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character"
        if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {
            
            URLSession
                .shared
                .dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                        
                        if let error = error {
                            self?.hasError = true
                            self?.error = CharacterError.custom(error: error)
                            
                        } else {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                            
                            if let data = data,
                               let characters = try? decoder.decode([Result].self, from: data) {
                                
                                self?.characters = characters
                                
                            } else {
                                self?.hasError = true
                                self?.error = CharacterError.failedToDecode
                            }
                        }
                        self?.isRefreshing = false
                    }

            }.resume()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewModel {
    enum CharacterError: LocalizedError {
        case custom (error: Error)
        case failedToDecode
        
        var errorDescription: String? {
            switch self {
            case .failedToDecode:
                return("Failed to decode response")
            case .custom(let error):
                return error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ListCharactersView**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ListCharactersView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authVm: AuthViewModel
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.authVm.logOut()
            }, label: {
                Text("Log Out")
            })
                .tint(.red)
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.top, 10)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                self.vm.getAllCharacters()
            }, label: {
                Text ("Refresh")
            })
            .padding(.trailing, 25)
            .padding(.top, 10)
        }
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                if vm.isRefreshing {
                    ProgressView()
                } else {
                    List (vm.characters){ character in
                        CharacterView(result: character)
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                    .navigationTitle("Characters")
                }
            }
            .onAppear(){
                self.vm.getAllCharacters()
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $vm.hasError, error: vm.error) {
                Button(action: vm.getAllCharacters) {
                    Text("Retry")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListCharactersView()
}
```

**CharacterView**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CharacterView: View {
    
    let result: Result
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(result.name)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
    }
}

#Preview{
    CharacterView(result: .init(id: 0, name: "String"))
}
```

I know the architecture is not as clean as I should be, but as I said, I'm new with Swift, so please, if I'm making any error asking this way don't unvote the question.

Comment: Instead of `try?` (which just throws away the error) use `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` inside `catch` to see the actual error. Besides that, you can also paste the JSON into app.quicktype.io and compare the models it generates with yours

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for your answer. I was having this error: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
So I have change this lines in **ViewModel**: `let characters = try decoder.decode(Character.self, from: data)
                                self?.characters = characters.results`

Comment: Unfortunately the tutorial you're following is wrong, in SwiftUI you shouldn't be using view model objects and should only use a hierarchy of `View` structs. You might be able to hack your way around this problem but will just run into more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @malhal. Then, What architecture would you recommend following to someone who has started programming in swiftUI?

Comment: SwiftUI is its own architecture already. I recommend learning `View`, `body`, `@State` and `@Binding` they all have a lot of magic going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the error as @jnpdx said in comments:

`typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

This how **ViewModel** looks like with the solution:

**ViewModel**

```
import Foundation

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var characters: [Result] = []
    @Published var hasError = false
    @Published var error: CharacterError?
    @Published private(set) var isRefreshing = false
    
    func getAllCharacters() {
        
        hasError = false
        isRefreshing = true
        
        let baseURL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character"
        if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                    do {
                        if let error = error {
                            self?.hasError = true
                            self?.error = CharacterError.custom(error: error)
                        } else {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                            
                            if let data = data {
                                let characters = try decoder.decode(Character.self, from: data)
                                self?.characters = characters.results
                            } else {
                                self?.hasError = true
                                self?.error = CharacterError.failedToDecode
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        self?.hasError = true
                        self?.error = CharacterError.custom(error: error)
                        print(error)
                    }
                    self?.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewModel {
    enum CharacterError: LocalizedError {
        case custom (error: Error)
        case failedToDecode
        
        var errorDescription: String? {
            switch self {
            case .failedToDecode:
                return("Failed to decode response")
            case .custom(let error):
                return error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
}
```